# spreading lists using three-dot operator in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var greet = ['Hello', 'World'];
print(...greet); // Using spread operator
```

can you tell me what is wrong with this code above, and how to use three dot-operator correctly in dart, and I am using the last version of dart

and how can I do something like this in dart, in javascript we use three dots

```
function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(sum(...numbers));// expected output: 6
```

Comment: The spread operator is meant to insert the elements of a collection into another collection. For example, `var collectionA = [...collectionB, ‘hey’, ‘hello’] `.

Answer (score 0):

Dart introduced the **spread operator** in `Dart 2.3`. So I'm wondering if you have the correct version.

Your use case looks correct. So I assume your version of dart doesn't support the spread operator:

You can see from their docs here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator